# Is os.replace() atomic on Windows?

Tags: python

In the docs it says that replacing files are guaranteed to be atomic on POSIX systems. Does this mean that it's not atomic on Windows?

Comment: The docs actually say "If successful, the renaming will be an atomic operation", and then in parenthesis "((this is a POSIX requirement)". So it reads, to me at least, like the operation on all OSes is atomic if successful, and the POSIX thing perhaps added motivation for this.

Comment: Relevant dialogue from Python bug tracker: https://bugs.python.org/issue27886

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As visible in [this thread](https://bugs.python.org/issue8828) the atomic replace functionality for windows has been added for version 3.3.

The patch is visible [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/80ddbd822227).

In the background `MoveFileEx` with when nessesary the `MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING` flag added is called.

`MoveFileEx` is the same method as the [openjdk calls](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/nio/fs/WindowsFileCopy.java.html). I can't find any documentation stating it is atomic, but the community seems to rely on it.

Comment: The MSVC STL guys claim that `MoveFileEx` is atomic, and `SetFileInformationByHandle`+`FileRenameInfoEx` might also be. See https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/2062#issuecomment-1139106197