# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.posixemulation'

Tags: python, flask

Hitting this error when deploying a Python Flask website:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.posixemulation'

I found this [Chinese link](https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_37254196/article/details/116995533) that says to install werkzeug.

So I did a `pip install werkzeug` locally and then a `pip freeze` and it says the version was
**Werkzeug==2.0.1**

I added Werkzeug==2.0.1 to the requirements, however I still get the error when spinning up the Flask website.

The issue has been reported: https://github.com/pallets/secure-cookie/issues/12

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the binary repository for the previous version. In our case it was 1.0.1

**Solution**

Add Werkzeug Module to the Requirements.txt file explicitly specifying the previous version 1.0.1, eg:

```
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

If your Python Flask website deployment is not automated (like mine with Infrastructure As Code) then you'll need to uninstall first:

```
pip uninstall Werkzeug
```

Comment: thank you. it works on mine. mac big sur, python 3.8

Comment: Fixed my odoo 15 installation on, Debian 5.14.16-1kali1 python 3.9.10

Answer (score 2):

Works like this as well:

```
pip uninstall Werkzeug    
pip install Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of your flask extensions is requiring an old version of Wekzeug. Fist I would check where it is failing, for example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/home/.../lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_caching/.../filesystem.py", line 7, in <module>
    from werkzeug.posixemulation import rename
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.posixemulation'
```

Here I am using an old version of "flask_caching" where flask 2.0.x was not upgraded. In this case the solution is to upgrade "flask_caching" to the last version (which uses flask 2.0.x).

*Your specific case* with `secure-cookie` (got it from the issue link). If your extension did not upgrade to use flask 2.0.x or depends on an old version of Werkzeug you need to downgrade flask to "~=1.1.0" as flask 2.0.x bumps minimum versions of other Pallets projects (including Werkzeug >= 2).

Answer (score 1):

`werkzeug.posixemulation` was removed in [#1759](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1759)

> ```py
> from werkzeug.posixemulation import rename
> ```

`werkzeug.posixemulation.rename` was used to get a "unix rename" on windows

since python 3.3, "unix rename" is provided by `os.replace`

→ duplicate of [Is os.replace() atomic on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862186/is-os-replace-atomic-on-windows)

drop-in replacement:

```py
from os import replace as rename
```